# customize HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden error view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have a web site in mvc3 razor on .net4 in my site if you enter an directory to browse it in explorer it give you this error :

```
Error Summary
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

how can i handle it until when user enter directory see my custom error page not iis error page i google it but can not found any solution for my case i have this lines in by web.config

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

and

```
 <customErrors  defaultRedirect="/CustomErrors/FileNotFound.htm" mode="RemoteOnly">
  <error  statusCode="404" redirect="/CustomErrors/FileNotFound.htm" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="/CustomErrors/FileNotFound.htm"  />
</customErrors>
```

but not works

thanks all